# App terminating when button clicked

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am very new to iphone coding.

I followed [this tutorial](http://servin.com/iphone/iPhone-Buttons.html) to make a button in an app, but instead of having it change the background colour in the app, I made it a weblink using:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"]];
```

This all works find when doing it in a "Window based application", but if I follow the exact same guide when putting a button into a Tab Bar Application I run into trouble.

The app builds fine, but when I click the button the application just terminates.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does XCode say when it terminates? Is there a stack trace? Can you post more information?

Comment: Select Run from the menu then debugger and have a look at why its crashed.  Also is there any error message in the bottom left of the X-Code window?  Also you ARE doing Run -> Debug to start the code aren't you?

Comment: The last line in the debugger is: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

Answer (score 0):

We'd need some actual code to really debug the matter but EXC_BAD_ACCESS means you're trying to access an object that has already been deallocated from memory.